# Facebook SDK iOS: Add post to feed with image

Tags: ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I have figured out how to add a post to my users feed, but currently it requires using an image URL:

```
// The action links to be shown with the post in the feed
NSArray* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  self.title,@"name",self.url,@"link", nil], nil];
NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];

// Dialog parameters
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               self.title, @"name",
                               @"Created using My App.", @"caption",
                               @"Check out the thing I just uploaded!", @"description",
                               self.url, @"link",
                               @"http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/hackbook/img/facebook_icon_large.png", @"picture",
                               actionLinksStr, @"actions",
                               nil];

[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

I would like to upload a `UIImage` instead.  I have seen some people talking about using the `graph api` for this.  How would I do this and still be able to use a caption, title and message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace your four lines of code by these two :

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:YourUIImage, @"source",@"caption description",@"message",  nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/me/photos?access_token=%@", facebook.accessToken] andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

and 'YourUIImage' by your UIImage.
Hope I answered your question!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it helped me a lot. I'd like to note though that in the current Facebook SDK(I'm using 3.1.1), there is new Graph API, but it's very clear which changes need to be made in order for your solution to work.

Comment: Glad it helped you! and yes, my answer was 10 months ago, a lot can change with SDKs! :)