# Facebook share dialog does not post story with local image

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a story using the share dialog with the code:

```
[FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithOpenGraphAction:action
                                      actionType:@"myApp:myActionType"
                             previewPropertyName:@"myObjectType"
                                         handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error)
{
    if(error)
    {
        NSLog(@"Facebook: error publishing story: %@", error.description);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Facebook: publishing story: result %@", results);
    }
}];
```

I get the share dialog (showing the image preview) and press `Post`, then I get the progress bar but it doesn't progress, and then I get switched back to my app.  Not only that, the handler does not get called.  I am trying to post a story with a locally generated image, like so:

```
id<FBOpenGraphAction> action = (id<FBOpenGraphAction>)[FBGraphObject graphObject];
NSArray* image = @[ @{@"url": [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-poof-1.png"], @"user_generated": @"true"} ];
[action setObject:image forKey:@"image"];

id<FBGraphObject> object = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
[object setObject:@"myApp:myObjectType" forKey:@"type"];
[object setObject:@"my title" forKey:@"title"];
[object setObject:@"my description" forKey:@"description"];

[action setObject:object forKey:@"myObjectType"];
```

I tried posting using a link to an image on the web, and that worked.

EDIT: I've followed [this facebook code example](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls#share-localimages)

Answer (score 0):

I think property url is for image url only try post file:

```
    NSMutableDictionary *variables = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:2];
    UIImage *picture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"75x75.png"];
    FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];
    [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];
    [variables setObject:@"this is a test message: postPictureButtonPressed" forKey:@"message"];
    //the fbGraph object is smart enough to recognize the binary image data inside the FbGraphFile
    //object and treat that is such.....
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"117795728310/photos" withPostVars:variables];
```

Readmore

[Document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api)

[Sample app](https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/tree/master/Classes)

Comment: Hm, I'm not sure how this ties to posting a story.  I'm new to the SDK, and I don't know how to integrate the code you've provided with the object/action pair as suggested by the docs.

Comment: you can read the sample project  :) https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API/blob/master/Classes/oAuth2TestViewController.m

Comment: This code shows how to post an image into the photos album, not how to publish it with a story.

Comment: sorry!! my mistake you can try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971098/how-to-post-images-in-facebook-in-iphone-app

Comment: or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382246/facebook-sdk-ios-add-post-to-feed-with-image

Comment: Thanks for you help, but unfortunately none of these links relate to posting a story on Facebook.  Here is a link to the docs about this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ui-controls#sharedialog

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58205/discussion-between-huy-nghia-and-andrewz).

Answer (score 0):

I have not experience of share dialog to post local image but I have posted local image to facebook without share dialog. And it is successfully posted with image and message. My code for that is

```
NSString *message=@"your message";
UIImage *sendPic = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
    [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(sendPic) forKey:@"picture"];
    //fbShreBtn.enabled = NO; //for not allowing multiple hits
    [FBSession setActiveSession:[self appDelegate].session];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
     parameters:params
     HTTPMethod:@"POST"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
     id result,
     NSError *error)
     {
         NSLog(@"fb result : %@",result);
         if (error)
         {
             //showing an alert for failure
             NSLog(@"error : %@",error);
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Post Failed"
                                       message:error.localizedDescription
                                       delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];

         }
         else
         {
             //showing an alert for success
             UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                       initWithTitle:@"Post success"
                                       message:@"Shared successfully"
                                       delegate:nil
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                       otherButtonTitles:nil];
             [alertView show];

         }
         //fbShreBtn.enabled = YES;
     }];
```

It might be useful for you. Thanks.